# Definition of Hamilton operator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, mathematical-physics, operators, terminology, notation

The Hamilton operator is by definition a self-adjoint operator $H\text{: }D\left(H\right)\to\mathcal{H}$ with $D\left(H\right)\subset\mathcal{H}$ a dense linear subspace of the Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$. If $H$ is bounded then is the Hamilton operator an endomorphism, because $D\left(H\right) = \mathcal{H}$.

However, when we have a Hamiltonian of the form

$H = \sum_{ij}A_{ij}c_{i}^{\dagger}c_{j} + \text{h.c.}$

Then the corresponding matrix $A$ is element of $\text{End}\left(\mathcal{H}\right)$ (Ref [Symmetry classes of disordered fermions](http://arxiv.org/abs/math-ph/0411040) by P. Heinzner, A. Huckleberry, M.R. Zirnbauer). Why is $A\in\text{End}\left(\mathcal{H}\right)$ and not $A\text{: }D\left(H\right)\to\mathcal{H}$?

Comment: Perhaps $dim({\cal H}) <+\infty$ (?)

Comment: If the $c_j^{\#}$ are fermionic annihilation/creation, they are bounded.

Comment: @Valter Moretti: Yes, it is a finite-dimensional Hilbert space. But why is then $A\in\text{End}\left(\mathcal{H}\right)$?

Comment: @yuggib: But then it is an endomorphism of the Fock space and not of the Hilbert space?

Comment: @LarsMilz In a finite dimensional Hilbert space every linear operator is bounded. And if $H$ acts on $\mathcal{H}$, then the latter is the Fock space. But how is defined your "matrix $A$"? Without a precise definition is difficult to understand your question... (I assumed that $A$ stood for $H$)

Comment: @yuggib: Yes, this is correct.

Comment: I don't understand the question. $A$ is an endomorphism $\mathcal{H}\to\mathcal{H}$ and hence also a map $D(H)\to\mathcal{H}$ on any (dense) subspace $D(H)$. Additionally, if the space is finite-dimensional, any dense subspace is already the total space.